# Does this graph have Eulerian circuit paths?

Tags: graph-theory, eulerian-path

For this graph, do  Eulerian circuit path exist or not?
Basic definition A Euler circuit is a circuit that uses every edge of a graph
exactly once. A Euler circuit starts and ends at the same vertex.

[image]

As far as i know the B follows Eulerian circuit path while A is not, is it correct?

Answer (score 1):

both of these graphs are not eulerian. I explained why not.

Comment: can we say Figure B as Eulerian?

Answer (score 1):

None of those graphs have an [Eulerian circuit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eulerian_path) because they both have vertices of odd degree: $c,f$ in $A$ and $g,h$ in $B$.

Comment: Can you please check this [question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1568998/basics-of-bipartite-graph?noredirect=1#comment3194372_1568998), its also helpful for me

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't, its semi eulerian, if in a connected graph it is possible to traverese all edges exactly once and go back to the starting vertex, then its eulerian, a connected graph is eulerian iff all vertex degree is even.

Comment: Can you please check this [question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1568998/basics-of-bipartite-graph?noredirect=1#comment3194372_1568998), its also helpful for me