# Graph Picture for specified vertices and edges

Tags: graph-theory

Please, anyone, help me to tell is it correct?
Draw the picture of the specified graph (including any isolated vertices): Graph H has vertex set {v1,v2,v3,v4,v5}  and edge set {e1,e2,e3,e4} with edge-endpoint function as follows:

Edge    Endpoints
e1      {v1, v4}
e2      {v1, v2}
e3      {v1, v3}
e4      {v4}
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is correct.

You may enjoy playing with [Graphviz](http://www.webgraphviz.com):

```
digraph G {
v1 -> v4 [ label="e1" ];
v1 -> v2 [ label="e2" ];
v1 -> v3 [ label="e3" ];
v4 -> v4 [ label="e4" ];
v5;
}
```

[image]

If you want an undirected graph, use:

```
graph G {
v1 -- v4 [ label="e1" ];
v1 -- v2 [ label="e2" ];
v1 -- v3 [ label="e3" ];
v4 -- v4 [ label="e4" ];
v5;
}
```

[image]

Comment: can you please check this [question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1569137/does-this-graph-have-eulerian-circuit-paths)